# Unattended-upgrades pending reboot prevents shutdown from user

Tags: permissions, shutdown, unattended-upgrades

Running Ubuntu 14.04 in a public computer room, I have enabled unattended-upgrades and configured to reboot at 02.00 in the night. PCs are dual boot, so a user would reboot the computer in order to boot the other OS, but if u-u had installed some updates, and set it to reboot, then the users would not be able to do it by themselves: if they click on the gear icon, and then choose shutdown and Reboot, the system simply does nothing.

If I login as root and try to issue a reboot command, the answer is "another shutdown already pending", so I have to shutdown -c to cancel it, and thereafter I am able to reboot. This is obviously not what I want, because the users should be able to reboot whenever they want without my (or root) intervention.

Could anyone help me please in reaching my goal (=have u-u set to install automatically, and reboot at 2.00 in the night, letting the users free to reboot/shutdown when they want, without giving them root permissions)?

Thank you very much,

Andrea

Comment: Sounds like you have conflicting requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Stop Unattended-Upgrades from restarting the computer

Right now Unattended-Upgrades is setup to restart the computer at 2:00AM if the update requires a restart. This step will stop this behavior.

**Step:** edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

Inside the file look for the line:

```
unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";
```

and make it look like:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";
```

## Create a bash script to check if restart is required and do it if needed

The script below checks if the file `reboot-required` exists and if so, it reboots the computer immediately. Let's call this file `reboot_if_needed.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        echo $(date) Sytem restart required by: $(cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs)
        /sbin/reboot now
fi
```

Save this file as `/opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh`

Make this file executable:

sudo chmod +x `/opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh`

**Explanation**

When the script runs and the file `var/run/reboot-required` exists it will output some text that will be captured in a log file `/var/log/reboot_history.log`. Then the system will restart.

## Schedule `reboot_if_needed.sh` every night at 2:00 AM

We want to run the script with administrator privileges. So we use `sudo`. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This command will open the crontab file for the root user if one exists, or create a blank new file. Add the following line at the end of the file:

```
0 02 * * * /opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh >> /var/log/reboot_history.log
```

If you use `nano` as the text file editor, exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. The editor will prompt you to save the changes. Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the default file name.

**Explanation**

Each line in `crontab` has five time-and-date fields, followed by a command, followed by a newline character ('\n'). The fields are separated by spaces. The five time-and-date fields cannot contain spaces. The five time-and-date fields are as follows:

1. minute (0-59),
2. hour (0-23, 0 = midnight),
3. day (1-31),
4. month (1-12),
5. weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday).

Therefore, `0 02 * * *` means at 2:00 AM every night.

The line added to the `crontab` will make the script `reboot_if_needed.sh` run every night at 2 AM. The `>>` redirects the output to the `/var/log/reboot_history.log` file. This file will be created the first time `crontab` runs the script.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto for how to use crontab

## Why this works?

Unattended-Upgrade apparently schedules the restart with a delay. For example:

```
sudo shutdown -r 02:00
```

The above command schedules the restart at 2 AM. When such a command is in effect you get the message "another shutdown already pending".

We use crontab to take care of the starting the restart process at 2 AM, instead of scheduling it from within the `shutdown` command. Thus, there is no shutdown pending once Unattended-Upgrade has run. Any user can reboot the computer.

When any user reboots the computer the file `/var/run/reboot-required` if it exits is deleted by the system as reboot is not required any more. The computer will not be restarted at 2 AM by the script.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, your first comment just lead me to the idea of a cron script, and furthermore your detailed explanation is excellent. I will try it and report here the results. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that I have not tried it out. So, there may be some errors in the details. If you have a problem let me know in the comments. I will fix my answer so that it helps others.

Comment: I can confirm that it works perfectly as expected. Thanks again!

Comment: I added logging of each automated restart. The log file will include a list of updated packages that needed restart.

Comment: Thank you, that's great :-) Please could you just explain me why `/opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh` and not /opt/bin/reboot_if_needed.sh ? I mean, I know what the backticks mean but I don't catch why we use them here. Or, at least, I don't catch the difference between using them and not using them. Thank you!

Comment: Trying to go more deeply, I suspect the `` make the script don't work. Try to issue a `ls` command for example. But I can wait for comments by more expert people :-)

Comment: sorry I now realize the * 2 * * * , I suppose it's wrong and it would be correct 0 2 * * *  isn't it

Comment: Thanks @Angus73 ! The backticks were copy paste errors. These were used for formatting the text as code in the answer elsewhere in the answer and were pasted by mistake. I have used * 2 * * * and it worked as the reboot part of the script works only if the "if" condition is satisfied, and thus only once a day, but 0 2 * * * makes more sense. Fixed them now.